# Is it possible to continuously update a VS Code QuickPick menu and let users interact with it at the same time?

Tags: node.js, typescript, vscode-extensions

I'm working on a VS Code extension that is scanning for file differences within snapshots and as the results come in, adds the different files to a QuickPick menu. I was hoping to have it where a user could select to open or compare a snapshot file before it's done scanning all the snapshots, but no matter what I try, interaction seems locked until the scanning is complete.

Here's the relevant code that can be found:

```ts
let cancellationTokenSource: CancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

    const quickPick: QuickPick<HistoryItem> = window.createQuickPick<HistoryItem>();
    const disposables: Disposable[] = [quickPick];

    disposables.push(
        quickPick.onDidTriggerItemButton(async (historyItemButtonEvent: QuickPickItemButtonEvent<HistoryItem>) => {
            quickPick.hide();
            if (historyItemButtonEvent.button.tooltip && historyItemButtonEvent.button.tooltip === 'Open') {
                let openPath: Uri = Uri.file(historyItemButtonEvent.item.description);
                workspace.openTextDocument(openPath).then(doc => {
                    window.showTextDocument(doc);
                });
            }
            else if (historyItemButtonEvent.button.tooltip && historyItemButtonEvent.button.tooltip === 'Compare') {
                commands.executeCommand('vscode.diff', Uri.file(filePath), Uri.file(historyItemButtonEvent.item.description), `Comparing ${path.basename(filePath)} with history from: ${historyItemButtonEvent.item.label}`);
            }
        }),
        quickPick.onDidHide(async () => {
            cancellationTokenSource.cancel();
            disposables.forEach(d => d.dispose());
        })
    );

    quickPick.ignoreFocusOut = true;
    quickPick.canSelectMany = false;
    quickPick.title = `Currently loading file histories for "${path.basename(filePath)}"...`;
    quickPick.placeholder = 'Type here to filter by date.';

    quickPick.show();

    await GetHistoryItems(filePath, relativeFilePath, snapshotsFolder!, cancellationTokenSource.token, async (historyItem: HistoryItem) => {
        quickPick.items = quickPick.items.concat([historyItem]);
        quickPick.show();
    });
    
    quickPick.title = `Select date of "${path.basename(filePath)}" history file to open or compare with current.`;
```

and the GetHistoryItems function:

```ts
async function GetHistoryItems(filePath: string, relativeFilePath: string, snapshotsFolder: string, cancellationToken: CancellationToken, callback: (historyItem: HistoryItem) => Promise<void>) 
{
    const fileHistories: HistoryItem[] = [];
    const snapshotDirents: fs.Dirent[] = fs.readdirSync(snapshotsFolder, { withFileTypes: true }).filter(item => item.isDirectory()).sort().reverse();

    for (const snapshotDirent of snapshotDirents) 
    {
        if (cancellationToken.isCancellationRequested) 
        {
            return;
        }

        const fileHistoryPath = path.join(snapshotsFolder as string, snapshotDirent.name, relativeFilePath);
        if (fs.existsSync(fileHistoryPath)) 
        {
            let latestFileHistoryToCompare = filePath;
            if (fileHistories.length > 0) 
            {
                latestFileHistoryToCompare = fileHistories[fileHistories.length - 1].description;
            }

            try 
            {   
                const quote = process.platform === 'win32' ? '"' : '\'';
                cp.execSync(`diff -q ${quote}${latestFileHistoryToCompare}${quote} ${quote}${fileHistoryPath}${quote}`);
            }
            catch (error: any) 
            {
                if (error.status === 1) 
                {
                    const newHistoryItem = new HistoryItem(fs.statSync(fileHistoryPath).mtime.toLocaleString(), fileHistoryPath);
                    fileHistories.push(newHistoryItem);
                    await callback(newHistoryItem);
                }
                else 
                {
                    window.showErrorMessage(`There was an error while comparing file histories: ${error.message}`);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The source for this can be found at my GitHub repo: https://github.com/MattMckenzy/BTRFS-File-History/blob/main/src/getHistory.ts.

I've tried a bunch of different ways to make it async, hoping it wouldn't lock the UI thread, but nothing worked so far. I've also tried, as is setup currently, to cancel processing with a CancellationToken, but no clicks are even being registered and the token can't be requested to be cancelled.

Any help figuring out how to not lock the QuickPick UI or any alternative way of tackling this would be really appreciated!